# Pass text inside a tag to another tag using forEach

Tags: javascript, html, foreach, onclick, innerhtml

EDIT: I don't understand why this was marked as duplicated since the previously question didn't reply my issue.
Yes, it is about passing using querySelector but how do I do this using forEach?
Please revise this.

I'm trying to make a `figcaption` to be displayed according to its associated image. It's a photo gallery I took the code from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QghhoJBdw7A).

This piece of code works as fine as is showed in the video:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.image-container img').forEach(image =>{
    image.onclick = () =>{
        document.querySelector('.popup-image').style.display = 'block';
        document.querySelector('.popup-image img').src = image.getAttribute('src');
    }
});
```

But when I try to use the code I created to pass the `figcaption`'s text to the desired tag (see `.finalCaption` below), I got **[HTML ObjectCollection]** as string. This is the code that I tried and didn't work:

```
document.querySelector('.finalCaption').innerHTML = image.getElementsByClassName('caption');
```

This is the HTML code from where the tag text should've come from (it's several `.image`s because it is a photo gallery):

```
<div class="image-container">
    <div class="image">
        <figure>
            <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
            <figcaption class="caption">Some figcaption text</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is where it should go when clicked (it should have been displayed as a popup image like in lightbox):

```
<div class="popup-image">
    <span>&times;</span>
    <figure>
        <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
        <figcaption class="finalCaption">Figcaption text go here</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

What am I missing? How can I use each image's `figcaption` to be displayed everytime it is clicked?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for your answer. It seems it doesn't pass the `figcaption` into `.finalCaption` as mentioned. Do you know what am I missing?

Comment: `const popup = document.querySelector('.popup-image'), popupImg = popup.querySelector('img'), figCaption = popup.querySelector('figcaption'); document.querySelector('.image-container').addEventListener('click', (e) => { const tgt = e.target.closest('figure'); if (!tgt) return; popupImg.src = tgt.querySelector('img').src; figCaption.innerHTML = tgt.querySelector('figcaption').innerHTML; popup.style.display = 'block'; });`

Comment: @mplungjan It seems it is not working too.

Comment: Seems to work for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/rajk7q8u/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

innerHTML takes a string, but `getElementsByClassName` returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). The engine attempts to turn this into a string and you get "[HTML ObjectCollection]".

What you want is the text value, not the element.
Edit:

You don't need to use getElementsByClassname because you are passing in the element here `.forEach(image =>{`
You can get the element's text with .textContent

```
document.querySelector('.finalCaption').innerHTML = image.nextSibling.textContent
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `.finalCaption`'s text was replaced by a empty string. Perhaps it's because `.image` doesn't have text content? How can I pass `figcaption` through it?

Comment: @Elena try `image.nextSibling.textContent`, it should access the figcaption if it is next to the img tag

Comment: YES! That's it! It worked!
I had to use `nextSibling` twice since `figcaption` is inside `figure` too.
Thank you thank you so much!!